# Changing Initial ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

In my application, I was working on one main viewcontroller. After completing that part, I added tableview controller and navigation controller. I linked the tableviewcontroller with view controller using segue. Now the problem is that when I run the app on iPhone, it still displays main view controller. but I need to display tableview controller first. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show code / screenshots for what you have done so far. Do you mean you want to change the storyboard initial view controller?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the storyboard initial view controller. Thanks, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps;

Choose your ViewController that you want to be first opened -> Open Attributes Inspector -> Select "Is Initial View Controller" under View Controller tab

and it is done :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSUserDefaults to know if your app runs for first time

but before this setup, in your storyboard you have to check " use storyboard ID".

[image]

in your appDelegate.m you

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstTime"]){

      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstTime"];

       NSLog(@"first time");

    }else{

        NSLog(@"no first time");
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName"
                                                             bundle: nil];
        YourTableViewController *evets =   (YourTableViewController *) [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoardId"];

        UINavigationController *nv= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:evets];



    [self.window setRootViewController:nv];


   }

   return YES;
}
```

hope it work for you